# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project checkstyle

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk, maven-3

when i run `mvn clean install`, i get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project checkstyle: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/sana/controller/opendaylight/commons/checkstyle/target/checkstyle-0.0.2-1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :checkstyle
```

Comment: It says it can't delete `/home/sana/controller/opendaylight/commons/checkstyle/target/checkstyle-0.0.2-1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Try to delete it manually.

Comment: Maybe you open this jar with another program and then you can not delete it.